# Rails Controller behave weird with 'after_create' method. - 'undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, after-create

I am a newbie to rails. Please excuse this.

I am trying to implement 'after_create' into my controller, in order to make data into different table in DB.

```rb
after_create :create_order_confirm
```

It will call this.

```rb
def create_order_confirm
    my_order_confirm = OrderConfirm.new(:order_id => @order.id.to_s)
    my_order_confirm.save
end
```

**but,** every time I try to render 'new', I got error following. 
[image]

These are my full controller. (excluded not relevant part..)

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_create :create_order_confirm

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
    render "show"
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new # Error -> happen.
    @order = Order.new
  end

  ...
  ...



  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create_order_confirm
        my_order_confirm = OrderConfirm.new(:order_id => @order.id.to_s)
        my_order_confirm.save
    end
end
```

It seems my new method wasn't called.

```
@order = Order.new
```

If I remove the 'after_create :create_order_confirm' this line. It's working fine. 
Would anyone explain this? and How can I use 'after_create'?
I only want them to be called if the 'create' function has been called.

**EDIT**

changing order to @order didn't solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, pictures of code make it impossible to copy and paste when we're trying to help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to. what would you want me to do instead?

Comment: Also remember, when I remove 'after_create' line in the controller. the view is completely working fine. so I don't think there is an issue in view part.

Comment: *Huh*??... `after_create` should be in the model, not the controller. Surely this code won't even run, unless you've defined an `after_create` method yourself somewhere, that you haven't shown us?!

Comment: you were right. silly me. :(

Comment: Please try to close/delete the question rather than editing it, thanks.

Comment: How can I delete this question?

Comment: Please **stop vandalising this question** - that is a sure way to get moderator attention. You cannot delete it without closing it first. It has two close votes, it needs five. I will see if I can get some close votes on it. It can then be deleted two days later - ping me again at that time if you want some delete votes.

Comment: This is now closed. Ping me after two days when the "delete" option is available next to the share/edit options.

Comment: Thanks Halfer, I am not that familiar with how SO works. will try to delete this after 2days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
after_action :create_order_confirm , only: [:create]
```

after_create is ActiveRecord callback. Not available in controller.

Answer (score 1):

`@order` <> `order`. So, try:

```
<%= form_with(model: @order, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: nope. that didn't work.